# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when active mpm_event

Tags: apache, debian, http2

I try to activate `mpm_event`on my Apache (OS `Debian 9` ) and disable `mpm_prefork` for active `http/2` on my site. 
But When I do that, my site goes down and shows `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on the browser.

The following commands I used to do that:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
sudo a2dismod mpm_prefork
sudo a2enmod mpm_event
sudo service apache2 restart
```

In the apache log I see just this error:

```
AH00052: child pid 27520 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Is there anyone who knows what should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is because of Mod_Ruid2 conflicts with PHP_fpm.

When I disabled Mod_Ruid2 the site was back up and running without any problems.

```
a2dismod ruid2
```

> The purpose of mod_ruid2 is to allow run of scripts with the users
> permission when Apache is using mod_php. In that mode Apache is ran
> with root and child processes are being setuid-ed to the proper user
> so they can't touch other user files.
>
> The php-fpm is completely different approach. With php-fpm the apache
> does not compile php scripts - everything is done by external binary
> (called php-fpm). Therefore there is absolutely no need for mod_ruid2
> when you are using php-fpm.

https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/php-fpm-and-mod_ruid2-with-php7-1.56552/

https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=16041